# Django end to end testing

Tags: django, angularjs

I am working on a project whose front end is implemented in Angularjs and back end in Django. I wish to do end to end test. But the problem is Django does not serve static files during test. Which means necessary scripts for Angularjs are not being loaded in the browser.

I was hoping following url configuration would work but it doesn't.
At settings/test.py

```
TEST = True
```

At urls.py

```
if settings.TEST:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
        )
```

What is the proper way to make end to end test with Django and Angularjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about `LiveServerTestCase` which does not serve static files.

You can load static files during testing by importing `StaticLiveServerTestCase`

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase

class MyTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    fixtures = ['myfixtures.json']

    def setUp(self):
        # runs before each test

    def tearDown(self):
        # runs after each test

    def test_some_stuff(self):
        # test some stuff
```